# Update form throw an plug-in crm 4

Tags: dynamics-crm

I try to update an entity with a plugin. I use Image (pre) and stage Post with asynk... The databse is updated in real time, but not the form. Does anybody know why i have to "upate" two times to se the updated text in the webform and the value is updated in the database immediately? I want to se it "immediately". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With asynchronous plugin execution, the database is never really updated "in real time"; the asynchronous execution might just happen so quickly that it looks that way to a human's "slow" perception.
On a server process level, however, the code of an asynchronous plugin will run "when there is time", while the code that rebuilds the form and sends it back to the client is running "immediately" and will wait for synchronous plugins, but not for asynchronous ones.

If you want the changes your plugin makes to be reflected in the entity form immediately after the reload, the plugin has to be registered for synchronous execution.

As far as I know, for asynchronous plugins, as well as for workflows, there is no timeframe in which they are guaranteed to run after being triggered.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meen is I want the webform to be updated "immediately" after i push button Save. The databse is updated, but not the webform. i.e if a do some calculation throw a plugin the result will be shown after i I have saved the webform two times.

Comment: The form will *never* immediately reflect changes made to the database by an *asynchronous* plugin triggered by saving the form. As I said, what you want to do can only be achieved by having the plugin execute in synchronous mode.

Comment: It is in PRE stage and synchronous mode, and the image in PRE as well... Do I have registred it correct?        DynamicEntity updateEntity = (DynamicEntity)context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"]; and update with     updateEntity["new_total"] = new CrmMoney("value");

Comment: Yes, a synchronous plugin in pre-stage is correct. Don't forget to write your modified record back into the target before the plugin exits: `context.InputParameters["Target"] = updateEntity;`

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn´t work. It´s close, but not working...   I would be pleased if You can tell my wath´s wrong with the code... Everything works fine except the "realtime"  update (=new_total) in the webform...

Comment: public void Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context){DynamicEntity entity = (DynamicEntity)context.PreEntityImages["PreCalculate"];context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"]; DynamicEntity updateEntity = (DynamicEntitycontext.InputParameters.Properties["Target"]; if (entity.Name == "new_underlag") {decimal provis = 0;
string constant = GetValue(entity, "new_antal", "");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(constant)) {CrmNumber antal = (CrmNumber)entity.Properties["new_antal"]; provis = antal.Value }  updateEntity["new_total"] = new CrmMoney(provis);  context.InputParameters["Target"] = updateEntity;

Comment: Doesn't look wrong to me. What value does `new_total` have after the form reloads ? Is it 0 or empty (which would be `null`) ?

Comment: ...new_total will be updated after I have saved two (2) times (in the database it updates perfect, but not in the webform).

Comment: It doesn´t worc. :-( anybody who has any sample how to update a webform throw a PlugIn? Thanks...

Comment: I am also having this problem? Form not updating till I manually hit F5 after plugin update? Any luck with this?

Comment: That was so long ago.... You might want to create a new question and describe exactly what you are doing, what you expect to happen and what actually happens. It might be easier to solve that way than here in the comments of an ancient post.